# How can you ensure registered atexit function will run with AppHelper.runEventLoop() in PyObjC?

Tags: python, pyobjc, atexit

I'm just wondering why I my registered an atexit function... e.g.

```
import atexit
atexit.register(somefunc)
...
AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

Of course I know when will `atexit` won't work. When I comment out `AppHelper.runEventLoop()` the `atexit` function gets called. I also browsed my `pyobjc` egg, and I saw under `__init__.py` under `objc` package the following code:

```
import atexit
atexit.register(recycleAutoreleasePool)
```

I looked for any reference within the egg to no avail. I also tried surrounding a try-finally shell around `AppHelper.runEventLoop()`, and the commands in the finally block won't get called.

Hope someone could help me out here.

P.S. Assuming I don't want to use Application delegate's `applicationShouldTerminate:` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do need delegates, because otherwise the event loop can exit the process rather abruptly (kind of like `os._exit`) and therefore not give the Python runtime a chance to run termination code such as `finally` clauses, `atexit` functions, etc etc.